# USB disconnect ubuntu 14.04 LS

Tags: 14.04, usb, live-usb, disconnect, detect

This is a frequent questions, but there is no solution, I installed ubuntu 14.04 the USBs ports are disconnected, I just reboot one,two or three time then it will connect.
this is the output of `dmesg |grep usb`:

```
[   29.376705] usb 2-7: Device not responding to set address.
[   29.580760] usb 2-7: device not accepting address 5, error -71
[   29.692831] usb 2-7: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[   29.710358] usb 2-7: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=3004
[   29.710367] usb 2-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[   29.728078] usbcore: registered new interface driver rts5139
[   30.009124] usb 2-4: USB disconnect, device number 2
[   30.257612] usb 2-6: USB disconnect, device number 3
[   30.293655] usb 2-7: USB disconnect, device number 6
```

Comment: In latest portable HDDs they could be mounted again once they left not connected for few hours(>6h). Observed this in Transcend and Seagate 2TB Expansion

Answer (score 0):

I created my own udev rule. Create file: **/etc/udev/rules.d/usb-power.rules**.
Use **lsusb** for idVendor and idProduct.

Try this rule:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTR{idVendor}=="0cf3", ATTR{idProduct}=="3004", RUN="/bin/sh -c 'echo 0 >/sys/\$devpath/authorized'"
```